# Inserting elements with foreign keys to Database by bulk insert with SqlBulkTools

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use [SqlBulkTools](https://github.com/AgentFire/SqlBulkTools)   library for inserting and updating lot of data to my database.
It works great when used with classes like in the example shown in documentation:

Example class:

```
public class Book {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And inserting to the database:

```
bulk.Setup<Book>(x => x.ForCollection(books))
    .WithTable("Books")
    .AddColumn(x => x.ISBN)
    .AddColumn(x => x.Title)
    .AddColumn(x => x.Description)
    .BulkInsert()
```

but my class is not so simple and it has foreign keys to another elements, eg. it could looks like this:

```
public class Book {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string ISBN {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public Author BookAuthor (get;set;}
}
```

and in database I have column `Author_KeyId` and separate table `Author`.
I was trying to insert it like this:

```
bulk.Setup<Book>(x => x.ForCollection(books))
        .WithTable("Books")
        .AddColumn(x => x.ISBN)
        .AddColumn(x => x.Title)
        .AddColumn(x => x.Description)
        .CustomColumnMapping(x => x.BookAuthor.KeyId, "Author_KeyId")
        .AddColumn(x=>x.BookAuthor.KeyId)
        .BulkInsert()
```

but it not works. It looks like only property can be added...
maybe someone already used this very useful library and can help me with this problem?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL above. Do you need SQL?

Comment: I was trying to add "sqlbulktools" but it was not possible so I made It like this. But you are right, I will remove it

Comment: That tag was not present, I have added it to tag wiki.

Comment: For complexe insert I go for Bluck insert into a temp table. Then a SQL merge query.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the insert query SqlBulkTools is building likely looks something similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO Books
(
    ISBN,
    Title,
    Description,
    Author_KeyId
)
SELECT
    ISBN,
    Title,
    Description,
    KeyId
FROM #Temp;
```

...with the query breaking on the second-to-last line, because class Book doesn't have a KeyId property. You're giving CustomColumnMapping() an expression evaluating to an integer; it's not going to have any clue where it came from.

The best solution would be to create a data transfer object representation of Book that has the Author_KeyId property, then translate your collection to that new class.

BookDTO:

```
public class BookDTO {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Author_KeyId { get; set; }
}
```

Translate (using LINQ; this is just one possible method):

```
List<BookDTO> bookDtos = (from b in books
                         select new BookDTO
                         {
                             Id = b.Id,
                             ISBN = b.ISBN,
                             Description = b.Description,
                             Author_KeyId = b.BookAuthor.KeyId
                         }).ToList();
```

Finally, the bulk insert:

```
bulk.Setup<BookDTO>(x => x.ForCollection(bookDtos))
    .WithTable("Books")
    .AddAllColumns()
    .BulkInsert();
```